# Entailment Checking Description Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am reading a research paper in Description Logic.
 Say L be a knowledge base  which consists of axioms. Then $C \sqsubseteq D$ is an axiom.

Theorem: L $\vDash C \sqsubseteq D $   iff L $\vDash C \sqcap \neg D $

I know that to check an axiom (A) entails a knowledge base, we have to take negation of the axiom ($\neg$A) and add it to the knowledge base and we have to check whether  the new knowledge base is inconsistent or not. If it is inconsistent, then the axiom entails the knowledge base.  The above-stated theorem is confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

See [Description logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic). I assume that, for a knowledge base $L$ and an axiom $A$ the definition of *entailment* is :

> $L \vDash A$ **iff** for any *interpretation* $\mathcal I$ with *domain* $\Delta^\mathcal I$, if $\mathcal I \vDash L$, then $\mathcal I \vDash A$.

If so, consider the first "half" of the theorem; we assume that $L \vDash C \sqsubseteq D$, and consider an *interpretation* $\mathcal I$ such that $\mathcal I \vDash L$.

By the above definition, we have that $\mathcal I \vDash C \sqsubseteq D$ **iff** $C^{\mathcal I} \subseteq D^{\mathcal I}$ and, by properties of set operations, **iff** $C^{\mathcal I} \cap (\Delta^\mathcal I \backslash D^{\mathcal I})$ (where $(\Delta^\mathcal I \backslash D^{\mathcal I})$ denotes the *complement* of $D^{\mathcal I}$).

But $C^{\mathcal I} \cap (\Delta^\mathcal I \backslash D^{\mathcal I})$ implies : $\mathcal I \vDash C \sqcap \lnot D$, and thus we have proved that :

> if $\mathcal I \vDash L$, then $\mathcal I \vDash C \sqcap \lnot D$,

i.e. $L \vDash C \sqcap \lnot D$.

In conclusion, we have proved that :

> > if $L \vDash C \sqsubseteq D$, then $L \vDash C \sqcap \lnot D$.

---

*The same approach must be used for the other "half" of the theorem* ...

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot these equivalences. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_Equivalences